# .htaccess not recognising multiple ErrorDocument directives

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, directive, errordocument

I've never used `.htaccess` before, but I'm having no end of trouble with it. I know that I've allowed it to be used on my site because I have a custom 404 page that displays perfectly.

However, I have a custom 500 page below it that my website completely ignores. The main `index.html` is producing 500 errors because I can't get `.htpasswd` to work, but that's a different question. Honestly, I don't know why it will recognise one directive and ignore the other.

The `.htaccess` file is located in `/var/www/html` and the `ErrorDocument` directives code reads:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /err/notfound.html 
ErrorDocument 500 /err/intser.html
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It matters how the 500 is generated/forwarded, ErrorDocument doesn't apply if a CGI or Proxied response, for example, just has a status code of 500 but was succesfully generated.    You'd see whatever accompanied the original 500.

Another likely cause is that a recursive 500 was generated trying to serve your custom document.   The browser error would tell you all of that, though.